# Trying to store data in a LinkedList on my test android app and keep getting a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception, linked-list

Problem: (All info below) I've set up the app to get text from `EditText` component and add it into a `LinkedList` once the button is pressed.

Tests: Testing for `getText.toString()` was successful (so u_in had a usable string) and I also tried to implement a simple array within my MainActivity and perform the same function which worked perfectly. Although I keep getting a `NullPointerException` with the database class and `LinkedList`.

I've also tried adding a null check in the `OnClick` anonymous method, but still got the same error.

Testing using physical device and running Android Studio 2.1

Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Data_base db;
public String u_in;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    check_button();
}


public void check_button() {
    Button add_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            u_in = etext.getText().toString();
            db.add(u_in,0);
            }
    });
}
```

Input class(Initializes information):

```
public class Input {

 public String input;
 public int age;

    public Input (String input, int age) {
        this.input = input;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Database class (where I have my linkedlist and methods to manipulate it):

```
public class Data_base {

   public LinkedList<Input> user_in = new LinkedList<>();

   public void add(String in, int age) {
       user_in.add(new Input(in, age));
   }

   public LinkedList<Input> getList() {
       return user_in;
   }

}
```

Error:

```
05-02 22:51:59.202 2813-2813/com.example.user.test_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.test_app, PID: 2813
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.user.test_app.Data_base.add(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
 at com.example.user.test_app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Initialising db might be a good idea

Comment: The db variable is not initialized anywhere and thus would be null at that point. As @SleimanJneidi said, you need to initialize the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainActivity` you're using `db.add` without instantiating `db` first.

**Edit Addressing Comment:**

Not sure exactly what you're doing with the `age` variable, but generally there are some ways to programatically get the same variable from an entire collection:

1) Get the value while iterating over the original collection:

```
//Somewhere in your business logic:
for(Input i : db) {
    String text = i.getInput(); //Your class should have getters and setters
    //Do something with the text variable
}
```

2) Make a `List<String>` using a `static` method in your `Input` class:

```
public static List<Input> stringsFromInputs(List<Input> inputs) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Input i : inputs)
        ret.add(i.getInput()); //Again, your class should have getters/setters
    return ret;
}
```

3) If you're not going to use such a static method often, then perform this logic where needed in the code itself (which you seem to want to avoid).

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, guess I'm getting tired. Also, if you sort of get the gist of what I'm doing here ... I've gotten a functioning list without any errors, although I only want to display the String input in the list, any ideas as to how I'd do this without creating another list with String input.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate before calling check_button() add:

```
db = new Data_base();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Data_base object first in MainActivity the try to do operation with add method